# jQuery fancybox post

Tags: php, jquery, fancybox

I have a jQuery fancybox that takes the content from an iframe, here's the link to popup the box:

```html
<a class="action_btn recommend_btn" act="recommend" href="recommend.php">Recommend</a>
```

and here's the code for the fancybox:

```js
$(".action_btn").not(".save").click(function() {
    $.fancybox({
        'width' : 560,
        'height' : 530,
        'autoScale' : false,
        'transitionIn' : 'none',
        'transitionOut' : 'none',
        'type' : 'iframe',
        'href' : $(this).attr('href')
    });

    return false;
});
```

now I would like to post something to this recommend.php, so I can use this attribute/value in recommend.php, how can I do this?

One way I can think of is to store a session in the page prior to hyperlinking, but doesn't seem right.. seems like there should be a better way to do this

Comment: I assume you need it to be Post and not Get (?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should still be able to use the _GET http variable I think so:

```
<a href="recommend.php?some_variable=value">Click</a>
```

Then in recommend.php use `$_GET['some_variable']`. Unless fancybox does something crazy with iFrames.

Comment: The only way you could do it with a POST would be to change the anchor tags for button of which the parent form has a target="your_iframe" attribute. It's a lot of effort though if a GET will work just as well

Answer (score -1):

since you already are using jQuery and possibly want to do this on the fly use .post().

```
$(".action_btn").not(".save").click(function() {
    $.fancybox({
        'width' : 560,
        'height' : 530,
        'autoScale' : false,
        'transitionIn' : 'none',
        'transitionOut' : 'none',
        'type' : 'iframe',
        'href' : $(this).attr('href')
    });


    // example uses a json object to pass data, change here to what you need.
    // will also accept jQuery objects like so:
    // $.post('recommend.php', $('#myData').serialize());    

    $.post('recommend.php', { name: 'John', time: '2pm' } );


    return false;
});
```

Comment: That wouldn't register the POST data in the iFrame it would send it to a new instance of recommend.php

Comment: hmm, you could take the returned data from the post and use it to construct your fancy box. `$.post('recommend.php', function(data) {
  $('.result').html(data);
});`

Comment: But then you're still going to have to send the data to the fancybox which was his original question.

Comment: unfortunately that's the nature of posting... sending data